# Unexpected output in converting numeric variable to a dummy variable in data frame - R

Tags: r, dataframe, dummy-data

I have this numerical variable in a data frame in R:

```
> head(sdbone$ncorrectas)
[1] 29 14 21 12 17  6
```

Then, I try to convert it to a dummy variable based on the condition that if ncorrectas > 10 it should have the value 1, otherwise 0:

I tried the following code :

```
> sdbone$ncorrectas < - ifelse(sdbone$ncorrectas > 10,1,0)
```

However, the variable doesn't change at all. So what's wrong with my code? and How Can I convert it to a dummy variable as I want to ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo

Comment: I didn't know how necessary is avoid space between < and - . I thought it was the same as <- . That was the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the space between `<` and `-`  ;)

Also,  instead of `ifelse`, use the following

```
 sdbone$ncorrectas <- as.numeric(sdbone$ncorrectas > 10)
```

Comment: I didn't know how necessary is avoid space between < and - . Thnaks!

Comment: no prob.  We all learned the same thing at one point or another :)